# AWS cli giving error when uploading a file without specifying the profile flag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm getting Access Denied Error when running the following command:

```
aws s3 cp your_file s3://my-bucket/
```

But it's running fine when I run:

```
aws --profile default s3 cp your_file s3://my-bucket/
```

My config file looks like this:

```
[default]
region = us-east-2
output = json
```

My credentials file looks like this:

```
[default]
role_arn=
credential_source=Environment
role_session_name=
```

My `aws configure list` looks like this

```
profile  default  env  ['AWS_PROFILE', 'AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE']
access_key  ***  env
secret_key   ***  env
region   us-east-2   config_file   ~/.aws/config
```

Comment: What is the output of `aws configure list` and the output of `echo $AWS_PROFILE` on the command line?

Comment: Can you please update the question with the updated info

Comment: I tried the command with both setting export AWS_PROFILE=default and without it. I have updated the question with the output @ErmiyaEskandary
the AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN I'm doing it as environment variables

Comment: Potentially related: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3304

Comment: checked the issue, looks like it was never resolved @ErmiyaEskandary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it: Here's my config file

```
[default]
role_arn=
role_session_name=
source_profile=myprofile
region=
output=
```

and my credentials file

```
[myprofile]
aws_access_key_id=
aws_secret_access_key=
aws_session_token=
```